# @Value annotation & NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces, annotations

I'm facing a problem with DI in Spring. My app integrates PrimeFaces & Spring and uses Spring for for DI and creating managed beans.

I have a `<p:datatable>` and when user selects a row and pushes button, my app openes a dynamic dialog with another grid to show selected row. I want to have two separate manged beans for each grid.

My .jsf page is very simple - just a `<p:datatable>` and lazy loaded `<p:dialog>` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:body>

    <ui:composition template="../templates/layout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">
            PrimeFaces webPage
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">

        <h:form style="height:90%;">
                <p:dataTable value="#{parametrySystemoweGridBean.definicjeParametrowModel}" var="definicjeParametrow" id="definicjeParametrowGrid"
                    rowKey="#{definicjeParametrow.id}" paginator="true" rows="10"  filteredValue="#{parametrySystemoweGridBean.filteredDefinicjeParametrowList}"
                    selection="#{parametrySystemoweGridBean.definicjaParametruSelected}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5, 10, 15, 20"
                    selectionMode="single" scrollHeight="100%" scrollable="true">

                    <!-- Columns -->

                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton value="Wartości parametru" onclick="PF('wartosciDialog').show();">
                        </p:commandButton>

                        <p:commandButton value="Odśwież" actionListener="#{parametrySystemoweGridBean.refresh}" update="definicjeParametrowGrid">
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </f:facet>

                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>

            <p:dialog widgetVar="wartosciDialog" header="Wartości parametru #{parametrySystemoweGridBean.definicjaParametruSelected.id}"
                appendTo="@(body)" dynamic="true">
                <h:form style="height:90%;">
                    <p:dataTable id="wartosciGrid" var="wartoscParametru" selectionMode="single" scrollHeight="100%" scrollable="true"
                        value="#{wartosciParametruGridBean.wartosciParametrowModel}" rendered="true">

                        <!-- Columns -->

                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:form>
            </p:dialog>

    </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>


</h:body>

</html>
```

First bean:

```
@Component("parametrySystemoweGridBean")
@Scope("request")
public class ParametrySystemoweGridBean {

    private DefinicjeParametrow definicjaParametruSelected;

    public ParametrySystemoweGridBean() {
    }

    //Some other stuff - getters, setters etc.

}
```

Second bean - here is the problem:

```
@Component("wartosciParametruGridBean")
@Scope("request")
public class WartosciParametruGridBean {

    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WartosciParametruGridBean.class);

    private WartosciParametrowModel wartosciParametrowModel;

    private WartosciParametrow selected;

    @Value("#{parametrySystemoweGridBean.definicjaParametruSelected}")
    private DefinicjeParametrow definicjeParametrow;

    public WartosciParametruGridBean() {
        this.log.info(this.definicjeParametrow.getKod());
    }

    //Some other stuff - getters, setters etc.
```

The only thing I want is to keep reference to DefinicjeParametrow instance from the other bean (that's my selected row). I tried to change my beans scope but it didn't worked. The second thing I tried was to autowire the whole WartosciParametruGridBean using `@Autowired` but it also failed.

When dialog is shown I have following exception:

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/pages/parametry.xhtml]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wartosciParametruGridBean' defined in file [...]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [pl.sygnity.cbop.admin.web.beans.WartosciParametruGridBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1007)
...
```

Please, could you help me in this? I'm really stuck and a newbie in Spring. I'm using latest Primefaces 4.0, JSF Mojarra 2.2.4 and Spring 3.2.5.RELEASE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object needs to be constructed before Spring can inject any values into it.

So at this step

```
public WartosciParametruGridBean() {
    this.log.info(this.definicjeParametrow.getKod());
}
```

The field `definicjeParametrow` is still `null`. You can always autowire parametrySystemoweGridBean directly into your constructor

```
@Autowired
public WartosciParametruGridBean(ParametrySystemoweGridBean parametrySystemoweGridBean) {
    this.log.info(this.parametrySystemoweGridBean.getDefinicjeParametrow().getKod());
}
```

I don't know JSF's integration with Spring (or vice versa) so I can't guarantee the solution, but the root cause is the one explained above.

Comment: You are AWESOME! It works perfectly and it's so simple! If you'll be ever in Poland just call me - I have to buy you a bottle of our best Polish vodka ;)